# Apache2 directive conflict with xampp through VirtualHost container

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel-5, xampp

I have Apache installed in my Ubuntu then I've installed XAMPP and added my **Laravel** project in XAMPP htdocs directory.

When I type localhost in the browser URL, it redirects me to Apache's default page but if I typed `http://127.0.0.1`, it redirects me to the XAMPP dashboard.

My problem is that I tried to make server alias to open my Laravel project from `(localhost/cms/public => cms.dev)`. When I type `cms.dev` in the URL, but it redirects me to the Apache default page as well but I want to open my Laravel project.

Comment: so, what have you tried before?

Comment: i am sorry but may you clarify your question?

Comment: Could you please show your virtual host directives for a Laravel project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation at http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost your virtual host should be similar to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName cms.dev
  DocumentRoot "/home/user/projects/cms/public"
  <Directory "/home/user/projects/cms/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simply to remove the `apache`  installation , because the separated apache installation was conflicting some how with apache with in `Xampp`, trying to stop that apache installation didn't work.